# Installing Jekyll on Linux Mint, Never recognized

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm, jekyll

I'm very much a linux noob, so pardon me if I overlooked something trivial.

http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/8081/53bv.png[image: ughh]

I installed RVM, and ruby, and am using ruby 2.0.0.  In the regular terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), installing jekyll seems to do nothing (even though it says success).

But for some reason if I do it in the Ctrl+Alt+F1 shell, it works fine and as I'd expect it to.  I have rebooted, re-installed ruby, still the same.

Is there something I need to add to my bashrc file?  or my PATH?  If so could someone please be so kind as to tell me exactly what to add and how to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got some insider help.

I guess in the terminal profile settings there is a `Run command as a login shell` that needed to be checked.  Everything works as normal now.